# What stod("5.000e-M1") should be answer?

Tags: c++, iostream

I run this program,

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::stod("5.000e-M1") << std::endl;
}
```

I expect this result:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stod
```

but I obtain 5.
It 's correct for you ?
Best Regards

I deals with csv file and if I have "5.000e-M1" I need an error and not 5. Do you know a function that have this kind of behaviour ?

Comment: ["it takes as many characters as possible to form a valid floating-point representation"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)

Comment: You probably meant `5.000e-1`. The "M" makes it an invalid floating-point literal.

Comment: Please explain your expectation of an exception.

Comment: I deals with csv file and if I have "5.000e-M1" I need an error and not 5. Do you know a function that have this kind of behaviour ?

Answer (score 6):

[`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) is specified to call [`std::strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof). From the documentation for the latter (emphasis mine):

> Function discards any whitespace characters (as determined by `std::isspace()`) until first non-whitespace character is found. Then it takes **as many characters as possible to form a valid floating-point representation** and converts them to a floating-point value.

`5.000e-M1` is not a valid floating-point representation, but `5.000` is, so it takes that and succeeds.